# JFileChooser.showSaveDialog() not showing up

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, jfilechooser

I'm using the Eclipse IDE, and I'm trying to call `showSaveDialog(null)` from another method which is in turn called from main, but nothing happens when I call it.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.pt = main.new PlayThread();
    main.generateSound(getSamples(2), 500);
    main.play(main.sound, 1);
    if(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().equals("save")){
        System.out.println(main.save());
    }
}
```

All the code before calling `main.save()` works fine, and `main.save()` starts like this:

```
public boolean save(){
    System.out.println("Calling save");
    try{
    String saveName = getSaveTo("C:/");
    System.out.println("I'm here now");
```

while `getSaveTo()` looks like:

```
public String getSaveTo(String def){
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    System.out.println("Save called");
    //chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(def));
    int resp = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        return chooser.getSelectedFile() + ".wav";
    }else return null;
}
```

After it executes the first few functions in `main`, I type in 'save', and the console prints:

```
Calling save
Save called
```

But the dialog never opens, and it never says "I'm here now." Why's that? Also, when I typed

`new JFileChooser().showSaveDialog(null)`

That shows up fine, but in my `save()` method, it won't. Any ideas why?

EDIT:

Here's a condensed program which has the same problem:

```
package com.funguscow;

import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import com.funguscow.Main.PlayThread;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test main = new Test();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean should = scan.nextLine().equals("save");
    scan.close();
    if(should){
        System.out.println(main.save());
    }
}

public String getSaveTo(String def){
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    System.out.println("Save called");
    //chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(def));
    int resp = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    System.out.println("Save called");
    if(resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        return chooser.getSelectedFile() + ".wav";
    }else return null;
}

public boolean save(){
    System.out.println("Calling save");
    try{
    String saveName = getSaveTo("C:/");
    System.out.println("I'm here now");
    if(saveName == null)return false;
    }catch(Exception e){}
    return false;
}
}
```

You can run this yourself if you'd like to examine it more.

---

This MCVE may be enough to reproduce the problem, and it seems that the Scanner that is initialized with `System.in` is interfering with the JFileChooser's ability to display an open file dialog, even when care is taken so that the file chooser is run on the Swing event thread:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter something and press Enter: ");
      scan.nextLine();
      scan.close();

      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
         }
      });
      // JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
      // int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you condense your problem into a single small compilable and runnable program? Please help us to test your issue ourselves on our own machines to better be able to help you.

Comment: Also, have you isolated your error? In other words, when you use a debugger, where do you see that the error coming from?

Comment: It just seems to kind of stop at `chooser.showSaveDialog(null);`

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I've tried to minimize your code further to see where the problem is, and I've posted my minimal attempt as an edit to your question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels your example work fine. Though the dialog stays on the background.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So all you changed was that you put the GUI functions in a new `Thread`?

Comment: @Aqua: It doesn't work for me. My program just freezes. I'm running on Windows 7 using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0, Java compiler compliance level 1.7.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels same config here with Luna 4.4.1 :) The dialog is not modal and stays behind all the windows. But if I comment out the Scanner then the dialog appears correctly. So your guess is correct.

Comment: Well I've at least gotten mine to work by doing away with `Scanner` and changing the confirmation to something using a `JOptionPane` instead. Guess I got really lucky, too, as it actually saves a playable audio file like I intended it to.

Comment: OP, my code is a simplified version that sort of resembles your code in that a Scanner is used with `System.in`, then closed, then a JFileChooser is created and displayed, but the latter is set up to run on the Swing Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: I tried running your last example on MacOS and it seems to work fine, although scan.close worries me, as you shouldn't be closing the System.in stream, but it worked with and without it. What OS are you running it on? Have y tried to run it out side of the EDT?

Comment: Sorry that should be "outside the IDE"

Comment: Also, your second example works fine as well for me

Comment: `}catch(Exception e){}` Never swallow exceptions. What happens when you add `e.printStackTrace();` inside your catch block?

Comment: @user2649681 is the information provided by me & the others helpful enough for you to select an accepted answer?

Answer (score 5):

`On Windows, Scanner interferes w/ JFileChooser -- why?`

**tl;dr** strictly speaking, it's the *user* that interferes with `JFileChooser` by using a `Scanner` expecting input from system console (`System.in`). Either way, it's just about the windowing focus and Java's `Dialog` modality.

#### Explanation

The bug happens because the dialog appears in the background because requiring `nextLine()` on the `Scanner` on `System.in` essentially forces the user to switch the focus to the console. The application loses the focus, so the `Dialog` appears in the background. The code doesn't "hang" by itself, it just waits until the user selects a file or does any other dialog option - until he does, it does nothing. If there's some kind of OS issue blocking the *background* window from displaying/working properly (e.g. some "always in foreground" window obstructing it) - well, then your app is *hanging* around, waiting for input event that's not likely to happen due to the fact nobody can use the input dialog itself.

For anybody affected - the `Dialog` *is* there. I've tested this code on Java 8 on Windows XP, Java 8 on Windows 7 and some other configurations - in all of the cases the Dialog *was* created, possibly hidden in the background of the desktop due to focus loss. It's not shown in the taskbar, but it *does* show in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> list. Try running it *outside* of IDE, they tend to do strange things with app focus when console input is required (due to "real" console getting redirected to IDE output window etc). Feeding it data through the `<` pipe instead of using "real" console will propably prevent this behaviour from happening too.

As far as my imagination goes, workarounds would require either forcing the focus to the app's Frame or creating an on-the-fly always-on-top Frame to keep the focus where it should be (on the Dialog). Since the `Dialog` of `JFileChooser` (or any other similar Dialog to speak of) is itself a fire-and-forget object, it's kind of difficult to force it to foreground without specifying a parent. Therefore, I think that the easiest way to go, for parent-less `Dialog`s is to just use code like:

#### Exemplary solution

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print( "Enter something and press Enter: " );
    scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame( "Dialog" ); // added
            jf.setAlwaysOnTop( true ); // added
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( jf );  // changed
            //System.out.print( "result: " + result );
            jf.dispose(); // added
        }
    } );
```

or, if you prefer to interfere with the `Dialog` itself, by subclassing it and applying the aforementioned `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` in the `createDialog()` call (note that `createDialog()` has `protected` access in `JFileChooser`, making it impossible to change the behaviour without extending the class, similarly to all the `Dialog` related stuff there), e.g.

```
int result = new JFileChooser() {
  @Override
  protected JDialog createDialog( Component parent ) throws HeadlessException {
    JDialog jDialog = super.createDialog( parent );
    jDialog.setAlwaysOnTop( true );
    return jDialog;
  }
}.showOpenDialog( null );
```

or even by creating a regular utility class extending `JFileChooser` doing just that.

<sub>NB switching to/fro EDT does nothing here, as this is *not* threading related by itself (though the multithreading of UI is the source of the problem, *kind of*).</sub>

Comment: I don't recommend using `setAlwaysOnTop`, it's pretty invasive to the desktop because it obstructs all other applications on the system.

Comment: @MasterHD I agree that it is invasive, but the thing is: if you can't force a blocking window to be always-on-top, it's quite possible you won't see it at all, and have a seemingly "hanging" app :D - the whole point here is to _obstruct other applications on the system_ so that the user knows that his action is required

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [answer by vaxquis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200988/838992) to be quite correct in that the chooser is being shown, just behind the current window as it retains focus.  It's all to do with `Dialog` modality and which windows take precedence over others on the various OS's (possibly in combination with some IDE's).

I have found the following workaround - keeping all your other code exactly the same, extend JFileChooser and then use `MyFileChooser` instead of `JFileChooser` in the `getSaveTo()` method.  I've tested on my setup (Windows 8, Java 7).  YMMV

```
class MyFileChooser extends JFileChooser {
    protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

This allows you to use the original construction (`.openSaveDialog(null)`) and has the nice added advantage that you can set up other features of the dialog box in your overridden `createDialog()` method should you wish.

***EDIT***

I see vaxquis [has appended](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28200988/4) this method to their answer now too, so that answer is, I would say, canonical.